# Notificação, mensagem de "Cadastro Realizado" Exibida ao clicar em um botão do formulário?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Como fazer com que o navegador, ou na verdade, o site emita mensagens como aquelas emitidas para você assinar uma newsletter de algum site. Quero que essa mensagem apareça quando eu clicar o botão de cadastrar...

Comment: Olá, postei o jeito mais simples de fazer, se deseja algo mais customizado, coloque, por exemplo, qual a mensagem exata que você quer enviar ao usuário e o que você quer fazer depois de exibir a mensagem.

Answer (score 5):

Este é o método padrão de enviar mensagens via Javascript:

```js
function msg() {
  alert("Botão Clicado!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="msg()">Teste</button>
```

E aqui estou montando uma simples chamada Modal via Javascript/jQuery:

```js
function msg() {
  $("#mensagem").addClass('ver');
  setTimeout(function() {$("#mensagem").removeClass('ver'); }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#mensagem {
  transition: all 0.52s;
  background: #FFF;
  border: #777 solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.52);
  position: fixed;
  top: -150px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  left: 25%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#mensagem.ver {
  top: 75px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="msg()">Teste</button>

<div id="mensagem">Muito Obrigado por sua Mensagem!</div>
```

Comment: Thiago Santos, essa é exatamente a solução que eu precisava! Obrigado!

Comment: @A.A.Marco marca como resolvida então man. Abraço

Comment: @A.A.Marco por favor marque a resposta como resolvida para que outros usuários também possam ser ajudados